# How can I select the nth row in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I have a MS Access database and I am working on one of its table. When I use the select query order by date, it gives 1000 approx rows. I want to display the 3rd row only. How can I use the select query that provides me with an output of 3rd row only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nested query would do it, something like this:

```
declare @table table (id int)
insert into @table values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)

select top 1 id from
(
    select top 3 id from @table
    order by id desc
) t
order by t.id asc
```

Edit: Just noticed you said it was MS-Access, The select query would still be the same

Comment: Thanks, worked for me

Comment: No worries, give it a tick if helpful :)

Comment: @dbajtr Literally thank you so much I was trying to find a solution for .accdb instead of limit like I'm used to and this works perfectly. Finally got a solution to a problem that was bugging me for 2 hours.

Comment: Hiya, I've tried this solution in MS Access and it doesn't work - it finds the last n rows from the table, and then returns the top result from that. So in this example, it would return the third to last result, whereas I want the third result. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Reversing the "asc" and "desc" should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you need it for? May be it is reasonable to use some Vba and Dao.Recordset techniques to show the result?

```
            Sub ShowRow()

            Dim rs As Dao.Recordset
            Dim intFields As Integer
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim lng As Long
            Dim str As String

            Set rs = openrecordset("tbl")
            rs.movelast
            rs.movefirst

            intFields = rs.Fields.Count

            For lng = 1 To 10
              rs.movenext
            Next lng


            For i = 1 To intFields
              str = str & rs(1).Value
            Next i

            str = Trim(str)
            MsgBox str

            End Sub
```