# Problem with returning nth row from MS Access table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to select the nth row of a table in MS Access (Office 365). I've seen both of the following solutions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45031166/1907765

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44891583/1907765

And neither of them have worked for me. When I wrote a query based on these answers, the query returned the last n rows in a table, and then selected the first result in that. E.g. if I was looking to select the 3rd row, it would select the 3rd-to-last row. Here's my query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Sense.SenseID
FROM
(
SELECT TOP 3 Sense.SenseID
FROM Sense
ORDER BY Sense.SenseID DESC
)
ORDER BY Sense.SenseID ASC
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong, and how to generate the correct result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order bys should be reversed:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 
    s.SenseID
FROM
 (SELECT TOP 3 s.SenseID
  FROM Sense AS
  ORDER BY s.SenseID Asc) AS s
ORDER BY 
    s.SenseID Desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a table alias so the syntax is correct.  Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 s.SenseID
FROM (SELECT TOP 3 s.SenseID
      FROM Sense as s
      ORDER BY s.SenseID DESC
     ) as s
ORDER BY s.SenseID ASC;
```

This assumes that `Sense.SenseID` is unique -- but that seems like a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've tried this and it still returns the third-to-last result, not the third. Is there anything else needed to make this work?

Comment: @Lou . . . Just swap the `DESC` and `ASC` in the queries.  It is not clear what *you* mean by "third" and third highest and third lowest values are both valid interpretations.  This version is the third highest.